# Lista de señales - Convertir lista a columna de Dataframe

Tags: lista, bucles

Estoy intentando crear una lista de señales de compra y venta de un activo financiero a partir de medias móviles exponenciales, pero al momento de guardarlas me sale un error, indicando que la longitud de los valores proporcionados en la lista signals no coincide con el número de filas en el DataFrame df. Al parecer no me está leyendo las señales que le estoy nombrando, pues cuando imprimo la lista solo contiene un miembro (0, mantener). Ni la lista contiene los valores mencionados, ni permite convertir la lista en columna (esto último pude hacerlo con la función pd.Series(), pero no toma valores la columna, me aparece NaN).
La lista no me toma los valores que le declaro.

¡Agradezco que puedan ayudarme!

Este es el error que me arroja:

Vamos a crear señales automáticas de compra y venta

```
Número de datos:
N = len(df)
N
Lista de señales:
 -1 vender
 0 mantener
 1 comprar
signals = []

for i in range(1, N):

  short = df['EMA_short'][i]
  long = df['EMA_long'][i]

  p_short = df['EMA_short'][i-1]
  p_long = df['EMA_long'][i-1]

if p_short < p_long and short >= long:
  signals.append(1)

elif p_short > p_long and short <= long:
  signals.append(-1)

else:
    signals.append(0)

df['Signals'] = signals
df

El error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-df5a3849ace0> in <cell line: 31>()
     29 
     30 
---> 31 df['Signals'] = signals
     32 df

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3978         else:
   3979             # set column
-> 3980             self._set_item(key, value)
   3981 
   3982     def _setitem_slice(self, key: slice, value):

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   4172         ensure homogeneity.
   4173         """
-> 4174         value = self._sanitize_column(value)
   4175 
   4176         if (

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, value)
   4913 
   4914         if is_list_like(value):
-> 4915             com.require_length_match(value, self.index)
   4916         return sanitize_array(value, self.index, copy=True, allow_2d=True)
   4917 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/common.py in require_length_match(data, index)
    569     """
    570     if len(data) != len(index):
--> 571         raise ValueError(
    572             "Length of values "
    573             f"({len(data)}) "

ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (1275)
```

Comment: Hola Felipe, bienvenido, tanto el código como los mensajes de error, deben estar en formato texto, no en imágenes, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, de esa forma lograrás que sea mejor recibida y evitarás recibir votos negativos.

Comment: Hola Marce, gracias por la recomendación y la bienvenida. ¡Saludos desde Colombia!